# Can the "Add Another Answer" button have its own draggable pop-up too?

Tags: feature-request, design, popups

If I recall correctly, there used to be a browser pop-up after clicking/pressing the "Answer Your Question" button. Now it has been changed to an in-site draggable pop-up:

> [image: in-site popup for "Are you sure you want to answer your question?" with a box visually consistent with the site theme]

Can the same be done for the "Add Another Answer" button (for reasons of consistency)? This is the browser pop-up I was referring to above, but for the "Add Another Answer" button:

> [image: browser pop-up for "Are you sure you want to add another answer?" with a box not visually consistent with the site theme; identified as "meta.stackexchange.com says"]

Mock-up for the in-site draggable pop-up for the "Add Another Answer" button:

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?                                **X**
>
> You can **edit your existing answer** to refine and improve it instead.
>
> Cancel                                           Yes, I want to post another answer

Comment: Note: The mock-up looks better on PC than on mobile, so if the formatting for the mock-up seems broken on mobile, it is not intentional.

Comment: It seems they've rewritten that dialog as a standard JavaScript 'confirm' popup, which is entirely rendered by the browser.